# python expression

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am new in python, and while reading a BeautifulSoup tutorial, I didn't understand this expression "[x for x in titles if x.findChildren()][:-1]" that i didn't understand? can you explain it

```
titles = [x for x in titles if x.findChildren()][:-1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with [:-1], this extracts a list that contains all elements except the last element.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[:-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The comes the first portion, that supplies the list to [:-1] (slicing in python)

```
[x for x in titles if x.findChildren()]
```

This generates a list that contains all elements (x) in the list "titles", that satisfies the condition (returns True for x.findChildren())

Answer (score 4):

It's a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension).

It's pretty much equivalent to:

```
def f():
    items = []
    for x in titles:
        if x.findChildren():
            items.append(x)
    return items[:-1]
titles = f()
```

One of my favorite features in Python :)

Comment: Suggest adding a link to the python docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 2):

The expression `f(X) for X in Y if EXP` is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) It will give you either a generator (if it's inside `()`) or a list (if it's inside `[]`) containing the result of evaluating `f(X)` for each element of `Y`, by only if `EXP` is true for that `X`.

In your case it will return a list containing every element from `titles` if the element has some children.

The ending `[:-1]` means, everything from the list apart from the last element.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a for comprehension expression.  It is simply constructing a list of all titles in the `x` list which return `true` when the `findChildren` function is called upon them.  The final statement substracts the last one from the list.

Comment: I've only ever known it to be called a list comprehension: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions . I've never heard it called a "for expression" before. From what language did you pick up that usage?

Comment: gah, i meant for comprehension and Scala